# What's the smallest subset of language features you need to bootstrap its compiler?

Tags: compiler-construction, language-design, bootstrapping

What would be the absolute necessary core features of a language (inspired from C) as a sub-language which can be used to write a compiler for the whole language?

Comment: Very broad question. Bootstrapping is a multigenerational endeavor with incremental expansion of features. You would start with reading a character from the screen, see BrainF**k examples.

Comment: Any programming language that's Turing complete?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a `while` loop, `if`, one *true* integer variable, and a way to read and write a file. That's it. (Actually, the file reading and writing part is nice-to-have, but not strictly necessary – You only need it to get information into and out of the program. And if you can read and write a file, then you don't need the integer variable anymore, since you can use the file as a temporary store.)

`while`, `if` and one integer variable is Turing-complete, i.e. it can compute any Turing-computable function. A compiler is a Turing-computable function. A compiler which cannot take any input or produce any output is pretty boring, so you need to have a way to read some input and write some output.

Comment: "`while` + `if` + bigint" is sufficient for a Turing-complete language, but not necessary. That is, you don't need all of these features to be Turing-complete if you have others (e.g. recursion) to make up for them. And you don't even need a Turing complete language to compile most languages. For example I can still write a Brainfuck-to-assembly compiler in your language when replacing the while loop with a foreach loop, which is no longer Turing complete. In fact you can probably compile most languages that way. And a Brainfuck-to-C compiler doesn't even need the variable (if we have IO).

Comment: I used Turing-conmpleteness out of laziness: I didn't want to go through the entire ISO C11 specification and figure out how powerful a compiler has to be, so I settled for Turing-complete, because I *know* that that is enough. And I settled for `while` + `if`, because the OP was talking about using a minimal subset of C to compile C, and `while` + `if` is readily available in C, unlike proper tail recursion, proper tail calls, laziness, or some of the other features one would need to e.g. program in lambda-calculus or combinator style in the minimal subset of C.

Comment: However, I just realized that the variable is redundant. I constructed my minimal language by first constructing a minimal Turing-complete subset of C, then adding I/O, but of course the file I/O makes the variable redundant, since we can use the file to store temporary results.

Comment: You also need arithmetic and/or bitwise operations to modify that integer. :) It's not Turing-complete if there's no way to modify parts of the tape.

Comment: @munificent: I think `++`, the literal `0`, and `== 0` should be enough.

Answer (score 3):

You can define bootstrappable metacompilers consisting of 20 odd lines that can do this.  The [MetaII compiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/META_II) is a particularly good example ***from 1963.***  I have bootstrapped much bigger compilers from MetaII as a base back in the 1970s.

These meta compilers require the ability to parse a metacompiler description (especially their own so bootstrapping is possible), that defines an EBNF syntax (test for input string, scan next token, ...) and a set of generator actions (output literal string, output last token scanned, output generated label).   You can implement a library in practically any language to implement the support for this in typically a few hundred lines in any procedural language.

Here is MetaII's self description, taken directly from the original paper:
[image: MetaII Self Description].
Yes, that's the whole damn thing.  (Exercise for the *really* motivated reader:  you can simplify the minimal supporting instruction set, and this description).

Here is a beautiful tutorial on how to build/understand this gem in JavaScript: [MetaII Tutorial](http://www.bayfronttechnologies.com/mc_tutorial.html).

Doug Michels, a grad student at Santa Cruz back in the 1980s, took this to an extreme.  If you encode language tokens as single characters, you can define a bootstrappable metacompiler that self-describes in 80 characters.  You have to get the thesis from Santa Cruz if you want to see the details.

Comment: There's a talk about Doug Michel's compiler as part of the Stanford EE380 Colloquium Series from 2009, given by Bill McKeeman, who was Doug Michel's advisor here: https://youtu.be/RGizBNflVKw

Comment: Sounds great. Thanks for the pointer!

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to interpret your question: as a theoretical computer science question; and, as a practical engineering question.

There's already an answer that leans toward the theoretical answer.  So, I'm going to go more to the practical side.

I think you'll need integers, pointers, variables, an if statement, a loop statement, and functions.  As the other post points out, you'll need to have some way of reading from a file to get the source code to compile and writing to a file to save the generated assembly or object code.

I'd suggest you look into the [Small C compiler](http://www.cpm.z80.de/small_c.html).  It's a compiler for a subset of C that is able to compile itself.  If you look at the [Wikipedia page for Small C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small-C), you'll see some books have been published about the compiler.  While the books are out of print, you may be able to find one available second hand.

Comment: I can easily write a compiler in Haskell (more easily than many other languages, I'd say - certainly more easily than in C) and Haskell doesn't have a loop statement. So even from a practical point of view, I wouldn't say that loop statements are required.

Comment: @sepp2k: Well, Haskell has recursion which you can easily use to simulate loops.  The question is, can you do it without function calls?  See my answer for one that does without.  Haskell can't go here; it is only function calls :-}